# Checking If There Is A Channel Containing A Word?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For some reason which I don't know, my code is not realising that there is a channel that contains the message senders username.
To use this bot, you DM the bot, and then it creates a channel that is named your tag. An example, is that my discord tag is Llama#0729 and it creates a channel named llama0729. The issue is that when the code runs, before making the channel it checks to make sure that there is no channel that contains any part of the user's username. It always makes a channel though.

```js
if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
        if (!client.guilds.cache.get('720571393636434031').channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == msg.author.username.toLowerCase())) {
            client.guilds.cache.get('720571393636434031').channels.create(msg.author.tag, {type: 'text'}).then((channel) => {
                channel.setParent('778216162403942401');
            });
        };
    } else {
            console.log('A Channel For ', msg.author.tag, 'Has Already Been Made.');
            return;
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're checking to see if any channels exist, you should compare their `tag` not their `username`. I've slightly modified your code and also removed the `#` from their `tag`.

```
var newChannelName = msg.author.tag.replace("#", "").toLowerCase();

if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
    if (!client.guilds.cache.get('720571393636434031').channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == newChannelName)) {
        client.guilds.cache.get('720571393636434031').channels.create(newChannelName, {type: 'text'}).then((channel) => {
            channel.setParent('778216162403942401');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        console.log('A Channel For ' + newChannelName + ' Has Already Been Made.');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work, although removing the # was a good idea.

Comment: I just tried it with `.catch(x => {console.log(x);});` after the `.then` to catch any exceptions when creating the channel and found I didn't have permissions. Have you eliminated that as a reason for it not working?

Comment: The bot has administrator permissions now

Comment: I've managed to get it working after adding `.toLowerCase()`, it looks like Discord transforms to lower case when creating a channel. I've edited my answer with the lower case and the catch.

Comment: Tsym! This is going go greatly help in the future and for this project!